# How to get an event when speech recognition is on

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I want to pause my music player when any speech recognition app is active, like the S Voice and the Google voice app.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to request Audio Focus and properly manage the OnAudioFocusChangeListener events from the device. See http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html for more information.